# How to manipulate a certain element when it is created

Tags: javascript, html

Much like the experimental [web components: custom html elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements) I want to replicate the behaviour but by using divs and certain classes and performing an action on them. Like so I want to do something with a element with a specific class as soon as it created.

For example:

```
<div class="api-list" data-api-link="api/users/1/posts" data-api-template="post-item.html">
    // List items
</div>
```

So with this, javascript should detect that hey a 'api-list' element was created. **Is there such thing as adding an event handler on the body to fire an event if 'api-list' has been added to the dom?**

Why not just attach it to the element directly, you ask? My site is single page and I use ajax to inject the content, therefore it needs to dynamically load things.

Comment: How about something like this event: `DOMSubtreeModified` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified - not very complete).

Comment: You should use jQuery for DOM manipulation; not JavaScript. It is a library created from JavaScript for exactly that purpose.

Comment: Or just run an update step *after* the DOM has been updated.

Comment: @cst1992 What's wrong with native javascript? Seriously.

Comment: @cst1992  That attitude won't help you really learn how to do things, and also, most of the times a giant library like jQuery is a bit overkill.

Comment: put the new content in a new Document Fragment, modify the fragment as needed, then inject it to the DOM.

Comment: @marzelin Wait, that's pretty clever. So the "in memory" document is modified before it is thrown into the document? Does it work with partials? I don't need the WHOLE document replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) can be used to solve your issue. [Browser support for Mutation Observer](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver)

You can check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KjltKxujzcxcCtjiQTa3?p=preview), I just created using your sample `api-list`.

We observe any change in the `childList` for the `conatiner`, if there are changes then loop over those changes and check if the conditions are met.

```js
var divApiList = document.createElement('div');
divApiList.classList.add('api-list');
divApiList.textContent = '////////THE LIST////////';

var container = document.getElementById('container');
var counter = 1;
function addApiList (){
  var apiList = divApiList.cloneNode(true);
  apiList.textContent += counter;
  container.appendChild(apiList);
  counter++;
}

function addNonApiList() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = 'This is not api-list div';
  container.appendChild(div);
}

// This can be in different file
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(mutation.addedNodes, function(node){
      if(node.classList.contains('api-list')) {
        alert('Api-List added');
      }
    });
  });    
});
 
// configuration of the observer:
var config = { childList: true, subtree: true };
 
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(container, config);
 
// later, you can stop observing
// observer.disconnect();
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Mutation are checked for the container below</h1>
<div id="container">
  <div>This is not api-list div</div>
  <div>This is not api-list div</div>
</div>
<button onclick="addApiList()">Add api-list</button>
<button onclick="addNonApiList()">Add NON api-list</button>
```

*Please Note: I have never used Mutation Observer in production, so I am not sure if there are any issues using it. Please correct the answer if there can be any improvements*

Comment: Nice, is it possible for the callback to also supply the element node that was added, so that changes can be made to it right away?

Comment: The `node` in `if(node.classList.contains('api-list'))` is the element added.

Comment: Great, just what I needed! One more question, does it fire when you're manipulating "innerHTML" ?

Comment: Yes, it does. [Check this, plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KjltKxujzcxcCtjiQTa3?p=preview)