# Do something when div is created without knowing the event that creates it (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wanting to create an overlay when a popup is created, but I don't know what event is triggering the popup. Is 'listening' for a specific div to be created possible?

Just in case that wasn't clear, here's another way of asking my question:

When `#popup` is created, I want to insert a div with [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/), but again, I don't know what triggers the `#popup`

In my specific situation, the html for the popup is being created *(i.e. the popup isn't just being displayed with CSS)*

**MutationObserver**

I attempted using `MutationObserver` but that didn't work. In my situation, when the input for the date is clicked *(see fiddle)*, the popup is created. With `MutationObserver`, I tried to fire an alert that went off when that popup was created. But it fires as soon as the page loads.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gdh261y7/)

Comment: Show the `JS` code please.

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36799656/2260614

Comment: Did you try using MutationObserver? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manipulate a certain element when it is created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36798010/how-to-manipulate-a-certain-element-when-it-is-created)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Mutation observer](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-dom-20140508/#mutation-observers) to detect the event when div is created

Comment: Do you happen to have an example of how it would detect that `#popup` was created?